# How can I have a substring of this string in bash automaticly in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have this two strings

```
select     chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name     from     snp147    where name="NC_0000/22/.11:g./42132048/_/42132049/insTT";

select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="NC_00000/1/.11:g./42132048/_/42132049/delTT";
```

how can I have in output the substrings

```
chr22 (tab) 42132048 (tab) 42132049 (tab) NC_000022.11:42132048_42132049insTT

chr1 42132048 (tab) 42132048 (tab) 42132049 (tab) NC_000001.11:42132048_42132049delTT
```

the numbers between the forward slash are the number that I want in the substrings

how can I do this in bash?

Comment: it's unclear, what is `chr22 (tab)` ? and what are the rules of replacement?

Comment: chr is a part of substring

Comment: Does the SQL have any role in this or is it just the text between quotes? What is the rule behind getting the number `42132048`  twice in the result?

Comment: SQL is for part of an other program I don't need SQL for the work I must to do

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ split($6,arry,"/");printf arry[2]"\t"arry[4]"\t"arry[6]"\t"substr(arry[1],6,length(arry[1]))arry[2]substr(arry[3],1,length(arry[3])-2);for(i=4;i<=6;i++) { printf arry[i] };printf substr(arry[7],1,length(arry[7])-1) }' <<< $str1



awk '{ split($6,arry,"/");printf arry[2]"\t"arry[4]"\t"arryarry[6]"\t"substr(arry[1],6,length(arry[1]))arry[2]substr(arry[3],1,length(arry[3])-2);for(i=4;i<=6;i++) { printf arry[i] };printf substr(arry[7],1,length(arry[7])-1) }' <<< $str2
```

str1 is the first string and str2 is the second. We split the strings using awk and the standard space delimiter. We then further split the 6th delimited text using awk's split function using "/" as the delimiter. We finally print the string with tabs where required and also use the substring function to print the parts of delimited text that we are concerned with.

Comment: I'm really sorry I forgot to say the the forward slash there aren't in the string that the problem, I put them to understand better

Comment: Either they are in the input and can be used to split up the string, or they are not, but then remove them from the question.